# Localizable.strings corrupted from git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, localizable.strings

Someone is cloning our git repository and having corrupted Localizable.strings files.  What might the issue be?  Sounds like the encoding is UTF-16.  Is this likely a network issue or a git issue?

```
/* divider label */਍∀ 簀 ─䀀 䌀䔀唀猀∀ 㴀 ∀ 簀 ─䀀 䌀䔀唀猀∀㬀ഀ ਍⼀⨀ 簀 挀攀甀猀 愀渀搀 䌀䔀唀猀 氀愀戀攀氀 愀渀搀 最爀愀搀椀渀最 琀礀瀀攀 昀漀爀 爀攀最椀猀琀爀愀琀椀漀渀 ⨀⼀ഀ "%@ %@" = "%1$@ %2$@";਍ഀ
```

Comment: "corruption" could occur when core.autocrlf is set to true, and replace eol characters. Otherwise, git shouldn't touch your files.

Comment: Its more than just the types of line breaks; its many Asian looking characters.  Any suggestions on networking issues?  Thats the only thing I can think of that is different for them than for me.